# What is the ideal way of filtering one pandas dataframe with the help of the columns of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["s1", "s2", "s3"],"threshold": [1, 2, 7]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id": ["s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s5", "s5"], "value": [2, -1, 1, -3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 6]})
```

I would like to add a column to my dataframe df1 such that:

- df1["newcolumn"] is, the "sum" of "value" in df2,
- for the respective id in df1,
- where the "value" in df2 is greater than or equal to the "threshold" defined in df1
- for each respective id.

e.g.

- for id="s1" in df1,
- There are three "values" in df2 (i.e. 2, -1 and 1),
- Among these "values" in df2, only 2 and 1 are greater than or equal to the "threshold" defined for s1 in df1 (i.e. 1)
- so, the code should return 2+1 = 3 for s1,
- In a similar fashion, it should return 3 for s2,
- In a similar fashion, it should return 0 for s3,
- In a similar fashion, it should return, presumably NaN for s5

I know I can as well handle this calculation via loop.

i.e.

```
df1['my_stat_column'] = 0 # initialize

for i in range(0, df1.shape[0]):
    s = df1.iloc[i]['id']
    t = df1.iloc[i]['threshold']

    for v in range(0, df2.shape[0]):          
        non_pythonic_and_stupid_way = df2[ (df2['id']==s) & (df2['value']>=t)]
        my_stat_value = non_pythonic_and_stupid_way['value'].sum()
        df1.iloc[i]['my_stat_column'] = my_stat

df1.head()
```

So, what is the real way of filtering one Pandas dataframe By the columns of another dataframe?

Thank you!

Comment: In the example, your values are strings by intention?

Comment: I edited this error. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

From your post, both `df1.threshold` and `df2.value` should be numeric:

```
df2.value = pd.to_numeric(df2.value)
df1.threshold = pd.to_numeric(df1.threshold)
```

Since we are working with aligned `id`, it's good to make them index:

```
df1.set_index('id', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

Then, `df1.id` should only have unique values, so, we can first mark all the values that are larger than or equal to the threshold:

```
df2['valid'] = df2.value.ge(df1.threshold)

df2['valid'] = df2.value * df2['valid']
```

Then you can do a simple groupby:

```
df1['newcolumn'] = df2.groupby('id').valid.sum()
```

Output:

```
    threshold  newcolumn
id                      
s1          1          3
s2          2          3
s3          7          0
```

**Option 2:** instead of setting `id` as index, you can use `merger` (after converting the columns to numeric):

```
new_df = df2.merge(df1, on='id', how='outer')

# similar to above, in one step
new_df['valid'] = new_df.value.ge(new_df.threshold) * new_df.value

# then groupby:
new_df.groupby('id').valid.sum()
```

gives:

```
id
s1    3
s2    3
s3    0
s5    0
Name: valid, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a shorter code, here's my answer

```
df1['my_stat_column'] = [df2[df2.id == i][df2[df2.id == i].value >= t].value.sum() for _,i,t in df1.itertuples()]
```

I don't think there's a one "real" way to do anything in python. There are many ways and you need to find either the most efficient way or the most readable way or etc. depending on your application